# Combine values of data.frame

Tags: r

I'm R-beginner, I assume this is not so difficult. I want to combine values of a `data.frame`, like this:

Input data.frame:

```
  col1 col2
1 a   50
2 a   80
3 b   40
4 c   20
```

Output data.frame:

```
 col1 col1
1 a [50,80]
2 b [40]
3 c [20]
```

In the input, `col1` is not unique. For each value in `col1`, I want to combine all values in `col2` in a vector. In the output, `col1` is unique.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entries of a data-frame cannot be lists, they must be atomic. What you probably want is to get a named list of vectors:

```
df <- data.frame( col1 = c('a','a','b','c'), col2 = c(50,80,40,20))
with(df, tapply(col2, col1, list))
```

which is a named list:

```
$a
[1] 50 80

$b
[1] 40

$c
[1] 20
```

Comment: A `data.frame` *can* actually have a list as a column, it's just not always the easiest thing to work with: `aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df, c)`.